# gradle test and main sets the same

Tags: java, gradle

For various reasons not worth getting into a discussion about, but that I think are very important -  I would like to only have one source set - the java source, and have the tests be in that - but I can't figure out how to do it with gradle.

If I point the test sourceset at the same directory - I get errors saying two source sets can't share the same root.

Is there any easy way in gradle to just tell the "test" task to just use the main sourceset?

Comment: I'd conjecture that going off the reservation here is somewhat worth the discussion, since this approach is *highly* unorthodox.  Notwithstanding the fact that tests can tend to leak more sensitive things in their artifacts, you would be publishing both source *and* test code at the same time.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: We code like this:

Comment: We code like this: class Blah { public static class Tests {  // tests of Blah... }   // guts of blah...  } - for many, many reasons that are more like a small book, and won't fit in 512 characters.  There's nothing extra released as it's trivial to filter out all *$Tests.class - but fundamentally - whether you agree or disagree with this style - I'd like to know how to make gradle do it?

Answer (score 0):

turns out to be easier than I thought, going a completely different way and just adding a new test task

```
task mainTest( type: Test ) {
    description = "Runs tests embedded in the code"
    testClassesDir = sourceSets.main.output.classesDir
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    binResultsDir=file("$buildDir/main-test-results")
    reports {
        html.destination = "$buildDir/reports/main"
        junitXml.destination="$buildDir/reports/main"
    }    
}

check.dependsOn mainTest;
```